# multiply list of lists by list of lists

Tags: python, list, multiplication, nested-lists

Does anyone know how to multiply list of list by list of list?

`[[0], [0], [12, 8, 0]]` by `[[1], [10], [1, 100, 1]`

**Expected result**: `[[0],[0], [12,800, 0]].`

When I try I always get:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst1 = [[0], [1,2]]
lst2 = [[1], [2,2]]
r = [a*b for x,y in zip(lst1,lst2) for a,b in zip(x,y)]

print r
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

In this example case, it works because `lst1` and `lst2` have the same number of sublists which also have the same number of integers items.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the form of list of list? In your example to get output: [[0],[2,4]] ??

Comment: Yes:  r = [[a*b for a,b in zip(x,y)] for x,y in zip(lst1,lst2)]

Answer (score 1):

Another way,

```
>>> l1 = [[0], [0], [12, 8, 0]]
>>> l2 = [[1], [10], [1, 100, 1]]
>>> [ ix * l2[k1][k2] for k1, item in enumerate(l1) for k2,ix in enumerate(item) ]
[0, 0, 12, 800, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are great, but they can get confusing, especially for a self-described beginner.

This way is (almost) equivalent to Adem Oztas' answer, except the nested list structure is preserved:

```
def func(L1,L2):
    result=[]
    for xi,x in enumerate(L1):
        result.append([])
        for yi,y in enumerate(x):
            result[xi].append(y*L2[xi][yi])
    return result

print(func())
```

The list comprehension version would be:

```
[[y*L2[xi][yi] for yi,y in enumerate(x)] for xi,x in enumerate(L1) ]
```

This preserves the nested list structure of the inputs:

```
[[0],[0],[12,800,0]]
```

The equivalent to Apero's answer, which is:

```
[[a*b for a,b in zip(x,y)] for x,y in zip(lst1,lst2)]
```

...would be this way:

```
def func(L1,L2):
    result=[]
    for x,y in zip(L1,L2):
        r = []
        result.append(r)
        for a,b in zip(x,y):        
            r.append(a*b)
    return result

print(func())
```

Both of these other answers (using list comprehensions) are better than what I have done above using loops, since this is exactly what list comprehensions were created for. But seeing it done another way can be helpful for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    for(int i = 0;i<lis1.size();i++){
        List<Integer> subOutPut = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j = 0;j<lis1.get(i).size();j++){
            subOutPut.add(lis1.get(i).get(j)*lis2.get(i).get(j));
        }
        output.add(subOutPut);
    }
```

In java you can achieve as above

Input : `[[0], [0], [12, 8, 0]]` * `[[0], [0], [12, 8, 0]]`

Output :`[[0], [0], [12, 800, 0]]`

Comment: Pravin, thanks for reply, but since I'b beginner in Python I have a hard time to understand it and I don't know which part I can use in my code. Are those brackets for dictionary also necessary?

Comment: This isn't Python code. You need to tag your question with the language you are interested in. Otherwise you will get answers in many languages or pseudo code (which isn't really a bad thing, just depends on what you want).